Start process in background on remote via SSH while keeping control over the exact process (PID) on the client
Surprisingly, it seems quite complicated to start a long-running process on a remote via SSH while keeping control over the process on the client to kill it later. Simply combinating nohup, <process> &, and echo "$!" isn't helpful.
For my use-case, it is ultimately important that the SSH connection on the client is non-blocking and runs in background, as the logic is part of a bigger script, where a final cleanup should kill the remote process. As executing killall <name> is overkill, kill $PID is definitely the better option. I tried various strategies, but none resulted in success.
Strategy A: Spawn sync process on remote with SSH session in background on client
This roughly translates to
[client]$ ssh user@host "long_running_task" &
[client]$ export SSH_SESSION_PID=$!

The problem with this strategy is that [client]$ kill -INT $SSH_SESSION_PID just kills the SSH process on the client. This is not propagated to the remote process. From looking at htop on the remote, I can observe that the remote process keeps running.
Strategy B: Use nohup on remote and save remote PID on client
This roughly translates to:
REMOTE_PID=$(ssh user@host "nohup long_running_task & echo $\!") which needs to be put in background
However, this runs until the task is done. There is no short-circuit! And none of the following attempts (pseudo syntax) can fix it:

REMOTE_PID=$(ssh user@host "nohup long_running_task & echo $\!") &
REMOTE_PID=$(ssh user@host "nohup long_running_task & echo $\!" &)

Therefore, it is unclear what is the best practice to get control over a long-running process via SSH and kill it eventually.

Best strategy to this phrasing alone means the question will be closed as opinion based. I recommend looking into tools such as tmux.

Thanks. I rephrased the question. It is a tough problem. I hope someone has any idea

Wouldn't screen sessions do it? I'm noway good at linux, so I can hardly forge an answer for you. But I do know that screen can continue running even when closing client and can be retrieved later on. One can name the sessions to retrieve it more easily, this certainly would allow to get in and stop the process.

One very simple, crude but effective way is to make the long-running task check periodically for the presence of a file called, say, /tmp/STOP and exit if it exists. Then your script that wants control just does touch /tmp/STOP Add the process id to the filename if you have multiple processes.

nohup seems like it would be counterproductive.  Wouldn't long_running_process terminating upon receipt of a SIGHUP serve your purpose?  Why actively prevent that?

You need single quotes:
REMOTE_PID=$(ssh orac 'nohup long_running_task >& /tmp/long_running_task.log & echo $!')


The problem

Surprisingly, it seems quite complicated to start a long-running process on a remote via SSH while keeping control over the process on the client to kill it later.

Tricky, yes, but ultimately not that complicated.

Simply combinating nohup,  &, and echo "$!" isn't helpful.

nohup is counterproductive for your purpose.  It ensures that the affected job will not receive a SIGHUP when its controlling (pseudo)terminal is closed, but delivering such a signal is one of the main ways to kill processes when a session terminates.

For my use-case, it is ultimately important that the SSH connection on the client is non-blocking and runs in background, as the logic is part of a bigger script, where a final cleanup should kill the remote process.

Ok.  There are at least two ways to do that.  One is to ask the shell to put it in the background with &, but you can also ask ssh to put itself in the background via its -f option.  These turn out not to be altogether equivalent.

As executing killall  is overkill, kill $PID is definitely the better option. I tried various strategies, but none resulted in success.

Issue 1
Normally, if you establish an interactive SSH session then processes running therein will be sent a SIGHUP when that session terminates.  The default disposition for that signal is to terminate the process.  This is why the shell (for example) on the remote side terminates if the session is killed on the local side. A great alternative for your purposes would be to achieve the same result for your non-interactive, locally backgrounded case, that still provides for easy management on the local side.
But as you've observed, when you use ssh to run a non-interactive command on a remote machine, that command does not automatically terminate when the ssh session does.  That's because in this case, the remote command does not have a controlling terminal, and it's actually disconnection from the terminal that triggers SIGHUP.  But we can tell SSH to give it one!  ssh -tt will force SSH to run the remote command in a pseudoterminal even in the non-interactive case, and even if the local end does not have a controlling terminal.  You can test by running this command ...
ssh -tt user@host sleep 30

... and then interrupting it with Ctrl-C.  If you monitor host, you will see the sleep command start, and then terminate when the ssh session is killed.
Issue 2
But if you append an & to the above command to run it in the background then you will find that it no longer works as desired (or I did during my testing, at least).  I take this to be because ssh does not like to be in the background unless you disconnect it from its own controlling terminal via the -n option.  I had trouble with the combination of ssh -ntt and & doing what I wanted, but using ssh -f to get a background ssh session worked well for me:
ssh -ftt user@host sleep 30

The -f option asks ssh to put itself in the background after performing any interactive authentication, but before running the remote command.  It implies -n, though that applies only after authentication.  That successfully ran the remote command for me, in a terminal, with the local end in the background.  Killing the connection resulted in the remote command terminating.
Issue 3
But then how does the local side know the PID of the ssh command?  It turns out that the $! special parameter does not report on processes that put themselves in the background like ssh -f does.  You could scan the process list, but that's nasty and fragile. OR, you could apply & to the previous command, even though it's already putting itself in the background.  This gets you the PID in $!, while not interfering with termination of the SSH session causing the remote command to terminate.
A solution
Putting that all together, then, provides a pretty simple and fairly reliable solution.  For example:
#!/bin/bash

ssh -ftt user@host long_running_task &
sshpid=$!

do_something_else
# ...

kill $sshpid

That's not altogether without complications, however.  In particular:

If the ssh command dies early, then it's possible for PIDs to cycle around such that $sshpid refers to a different process by the time you want to kill it.  You might then kill a process you did not mean to kill.

It is possible for the remote process to immunize itself against termination by SIGHUP.  We already discussed use of nohup as one way to do that, but there are others.  If this is not sufficiently under your control then you may need a different approach.

The same for other processes the remote process might launch. Such processes would ordinarily be sent a SIGHUP too, but there are ways to prevent that or to immunize against it.



This makes the unnecessary assumption that the ssh session remains as long as the spawned process runs.   I suspect the O Pintended tht ssh is used briefly to start the 'service' then is later used to kill the service.

Perhaps that is unnecessary, @stevea, but apparently it is nevertheless acceptable to the OP, being also a characteristic of their "Strategy A".

Have you tried -f ?
(I'm sending STDERR to /dev/null to cull the mod boilerplate noise for the example. Please DO NOT do that in a script.
Similarly, a public key login would remove the password, etc.)
$: ssh -f $svr 'sleep 999 & echo $!' 2>/dev/null
(paul@theserver) Password:
55405

$: ssh $svr ps -fp 55405 2>/dev/null
(paul@theserver) Password:
UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
paul      55405      1  0 15:23 ?        00:00:00 sleep 999

$: ssh $svr kill 55405 2>/dev/null
(paul@theserver) Password:

$: ssh $svr ps -ef 2>/dev/null | grep 'sleep 999'
(paul@theserver) Password:

$: 

To capture the PID you'll need to filter it through something that ends the stream - I used head -1.
$: pid=$( ssh -f $svr 'sleep 999 & echo $!' 2>/dev/null | head -1 )
(paul@theserver) Password:

$: echo $pid
68509

$: ssh $svr ps -fp $pid 2>/dev/null
(paul@theserver) Password:
UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
paul      68509      1  0 20:10 ?        00:00:00 sleep 999

$: ssh $svr kill $pid 2>/dev/null
(paul@theserver) Password:

$: ssh $svr ps -ef 2>/dev/null | grep 'sleep 999'
(paul@theserver) Password:

$:


Let's try it:
If the goal of this is to remotely run a long_running_task and to be able to remotely watch and/or kill them through ssh.
My long_running_task is, for this sample: sleep infinity.
remote=user@host
rpid=$(ssh $remote bash <<<'sleep infinity <<<"" >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!')
ssh $remote ps hw $rpid

 641699 ?        S      0:00 sleep infinity

Then
ssh $remote kill $rpid
ssh $remote ps hw $rpid

Where output should be empty.
One step further
my long_running_task become
export varCnt
while :;do
    ((varCnt++))
    sleep 1
done

In order to have some exported variable to watch for on sleep subtask:
rpid=$(ssh $remote bash <<<'export varCnt;while :;do
        ((varCnt++));sleep 1;done <<<"" >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!')

Then
ssh $remote bash <<<"spid=\$((\$(ps --ppid $rpid ho pid)));((spid))&&
                     sed -zne '/varCnt/s/$/\n/p' /proc/\$spid/environ"

Should output something like:
varCnt=4

ssh $remote kill $rpid
ssh $remote ps hw $rpid
ssh $remote bash <<<"spid=\$((\$(ps --ppid $rpid ho pid)));((spid))&&
                     sed -zne '/varCnt/s/$/\n/p' /proc/\$spid/environ"

Where output should be empty.

nohup etc work fine, but the ssh session does not terminate so long as the stdin/out/err are open by the remote "bash -c ..." . So to start the long remote service ("sleep 40" here) redirection is needed to avoid the local ssh hanging.
farpid=$(ssh  me@farsys 'nohup sleep 40 1>/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!')

We can kill the far process with ....
ssh me@farsys "kill -9 $farpid"

or similar.
